# function comparision to sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f : A \to B$ be a function, where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. Recall that a function is a
certain kind of relation, and a relation is a certain kind of set, so it makes sense to talk about
the cardinality of the function, $|f|$.

(a) What can we say about $|f|$ in comparison to $|A|$?

(b) If f is surjective, what can we say about $|A|$ in comparison to $|B|$?

(c) If f is injective, what can we say about $|A|$ in comparison to $|B|$?

(d) If f is bijective, what can we say about $|A|$ in comparison to $|B|$?

Solution:

(a) This means that $|f| = |A|$ because by definition of function it is a relation that each element of $a \in A$ is associated to exactly one element $B$

(b) If the function is surjective, then all $B$ are mapped to, but multiple elements of A can map to the same elements of B. Thus, $|A| \geq |B|$

(c) If the function is injective, we know that every element of $A$ maps to a unique element of B, $|A| \leq |B|$

(d) Since bijective is the combination of both of these conditions this implies that $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|A| \geq |B| \to |A| = |B|$

Would this be right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct for finite sets(for infinite sets (b) is not as simple)

Comment: @Holo for infinite sets by _definition_,  $f$ surjective implies $|A| \leq |B|$.

Comment: @GuidoA. No, by definition $f:A\to B$ *injective* implies $|A|\le |B|$

Comment: My bad, yes. I obviously meant $\geq$. My point is that every item holds for more general cases, because by definition we ask for these very conditions.